# how can i get a normal value form a series pine script

Tags: pine-script

in the pinescript I want get the value of a series like (security) to a normal value for use a operation how can get that value?  like
need_normalvalue_this_series = security(syminfo.tickerid,5,ta.sma(close,20) operation =  need_normalvalue_this_series - 150
but i dont have the value of series  how can get that value?

Comment: What do you mean by normal value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Each series shows a numerical value on the chart, but that number cannot be used in operation..
How can I convert that value into a value for calculation?